# Gmail test accounts for Android Market LVL testing?

Tags: gmail, google-play, android-lvl

I read the instructions on [how set up test accounts](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#test-acct-setup), but for the life of me I find it hard to believe that I need to go and create **real** Gmail accounts in order to list them in that "[Test Accounts](http://developer.android.com/images/licensing_test_response.png)" box.

In PayPal, for example, I can create as many email accounts as I wish, all contained inside the sandbox, never having to exit the sandbox environment.

Any idea how this goes with Gmail accounts for Android Market LVL testing?

Do I really need to create **real** Gmail accounts, even if they are only needed for the LVL testing?

Is that legit to have multiple accounts for a one-programmer shop?

BTW, I tried testing with my publisher account but it keeps returning "Allow the user access". So I figured I must have another, non-publisher account to test this.

Comment: Looks like that is the case. There is no distinction between a normal Google account and one made for testing purposes. "You can use any Google account as a test account. If you want to own and control the test accounts, you can create the accounts yourself and distribute the credentials to your developers or testers."

Comment: @dolphy Thanks. I am a one-programmer shop. Is that legit to have multiple accounts for one person? BTW, I tried testing with my publisher account but it keeps returning "Allow the user access". So I figured I must have another, **non-publisher** account to test this.

Comment: I can't speak to any external TOS conflicts or anything like that, but Google is certainly fine with a person owning more than one Google accounts. For example, see their support for [Multiple Account Signon](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182343)

Comment: @dolphy Thanks again. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that is the case. There is no distinction between a normal Google account and one made for testing purposes.

```
...
You can use any Google account as a test account. If you want to own and 
control the test accounts, you can create the accounts yourself and distribute 
the credentials to your developers or testers.
...
```